# Culling lines and points based on "normals"

Tags: webgl

I'm trying to simulate things like `glPolygonMode( GL_BACK, GL_LINE)` in WebGL.  I can draw with mode `LINES` instead of `TRIANGLES`, but I can't see how WebGL could automatically determine whether a particular segment is back-facing, because segments don't face anywhere.

To solve this, I pass the normal of the original triangle to the shader.  It's easy to calculate transforms of this under the usual modelview transformations (rotations, scaling, translations); then I just multiply the normal by the transpose of the inverse. Based on whether the normal points into the screen or out I can decide whether to cull a line segment.

However, this isn't quite right.  I need the inverse of the projection matrix as well to take perspective distortions into account.

I'm using the `CanvasMatrix4.frustum()` or `CanvasMatrix4.ortho()` functions to get the projection matrix.  Are there formulas or functions available for their inverses?

Alternatively, is there a better way to simulate things like `glPolygonMode( GL_BACK, GL_LINE)`?

Comment: You might like [this solution](http://codeflow.org/entries/2012/aug/02/easy-wireframe-display-with-barycentric-coordinates/)

Comment: I tried a solution like the barycentric one, but I couldn't get it to look like the `GL_LINE` polygon mode when using fat lines.  It looked like partially filled in faces, but weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of sending the other vertices of the triangle as extra attributes seems to work.

Here's the key part of the vertex shader.  Attribute `aPos` is the position of the vertex being used in the line segment; `v1` is the next vertex going around the triangle, and `v2` is the one after that.

I've edited the code to leave out the lighting-related stuff.  This probably isn't the most efficient implementation, but it does appear to work.

```
attribute vec3 aPos;
uniform mat4 mvMatrix;
uniform mat4 prMatrix;
attribute vec3 v1;
attribute vec3 v2;
varying float normz;

void main(void) {
    gl_Position = prMatrix * (mvMatrix * vec4(aPos, 1.));
    vec4 v1p = (prMatrix*(mvMatrix*vec4(v1, 1.)));
    v1p = v1p/v1p.w - gl_Position/gl_Position.w;
    vec4 v2p = (prMatrix*(mvMatrix*vec4(v2, 1.)));
    v2p = v2p/v2p.w - gl_Position/gl_Position.w;
    normz = v1p.x*v2p.y - v1p.y*v2p.x; // z component of cross product
}
```

In the fragment shader, discard fragments based on the sign of `normz`.  I use

```
if ((normz <= 0.) != front) discard;
```

where `front` is a `bool` indicating whether I want to show the front or not.

Comment: Struggling since days with a similar problem: I'm trying to get an early visibility check based on a normal tranformation, befor pass vertexes to WebGL. Did You find a cheaper way to achieve that, without the need of the extra vertices? It seems to me, I have all what I need to perspective-shear the normals: my camera is on the z-axis, I have the full transformation matrix, the fudge factor and the normals in object space. Still nothing... [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65970900/normals-transformation-for-back-face-culling) is my question.

Comment: Four years later I'm still using the code in this post.

Answer (score 1):

If using WebGl extensions is an option, you might want to look into [OES_standard_derivatives](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OES_standard_derivatives). This extension was introduced for the specific purpose of solving your perspective correction issue. According to [WebGL Stats](http://webglstats.com) support is pretty univeral.

In your main code base, enable this extension:

```
gl.getExtension("OES_standard_derivatives");
```

The extension introduces the dFdx and dFdy functions, allowing you to do a front/back test like this:

```
vec3 dx = dFdx(position);
vec3 dy = dFdy(position);
vec3 faceNormal = normalize(cross(dx, dy));
if (dot(normal, faceNormal) > 0.0) {
    // Front facing
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Take the area of the triangle. If it is positive, draw it if it is negative, cull it.

Comment: I can't do that in the shaders, because they never see any triangles.  So I'd need to do all of the transformations and calculations in Javascript and update the  `ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` with every frame being rendered.  It sounds really slow.

Comment: I suppose I could pass the other two vertices in as well, and then calculate the normals after projection...